# Взять по очереди значения из строки

Tags: c#

Есть текстовый файл в котором текст такого вида: `X56373Y57483W46373H4747A0`.

Можно ли на C# как то из предложенной строки вытянуть по очереди значения, например `X56373`, потом отдельно `Y57483` и `W46373`?
Если можно, то каким образом ?

Comment: разбить на строки по 6 символов или как?

Comment: например с помощью регулярки: `Regex.Matches(s, @"\w\d+")`

Comment: А по какому критерию разбивать? По букве?

Comment: Строку нужно разбить на подстройки, как я думаю. А разбить по критерию. X, Y, W. Но вся проблема в том , что помимо X есть числа... Поэтому нужно разбить по критерию X и по набору чисел после каждой буквы X,Y,W и тд..

Comment: @Jeron Регулярками и разобъете на группы. Потом, обращаясь к каждой группе распарсите значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов:

```
string input = "X56373Y57483W46373H4747A0";
string pattern = @"(X\d+)|(Y\d+)|(W\d+)";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(input);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать так:

```
string text = @"X56373Y57483W46373H4747A0";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"[A-Z]\d+");
var matches = regex.Matches(text);
```

Comment: не уверен, что нужен `\D`

Comment: @Grundy, сейчас проверил, действительно \D не срабатывает, подправил ответ.